# How to conver number of size N to string - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query is giving me out put in correct format

```
select  to_char(999.00,'9,99.00') from dual

output = 9,99.00
```

what if I don't have a specific size to the number?

```
999999999999999999999999999999999.00
```

should be converted as

```
9999999999999999999999999999999,99.00
```

Will it be possible to do that?
Is there any formats for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `FM` prefix in your formatting string. It trims leading spaces from the result of the conversion:

```
select ''''||to_char(123456.00, 'FM999999999999999999,99.00')||''''
     , ''''||to_char(123456.00,   '999999999999999999,99.00')||''''
  from dual
     ;
```

produces

```
'1234,56.00'                
'               1234,56.00'
```

**Note**:
You have to specify as many digits as the largest number to be converted will have in its shortest representation matching the format. Turning a complicated phrasing into a simple example, `to_char(123456.00, 'FM9,99.00')` won't work.

Comment: I know we have to way of giving all the 99999999999999 s . but is there any better way available? I dont know the length of my number.

Comment: Iirc, oracle numbers may have at most 38 (mantissa) digits, so use 38 `9`s in your pattern and you'll be on the safe side.